# LVM2 partially destroyed using the "fio" command in a wrong way - how to recover what can be recovered

Tags: lvm, data-recovery, storage, proxmox

i already posted my question on the Proxmox forum because that is the hypervisor i am using, however i take the opportunity of doing it here as well, the more people sees it the better chance i have to recover some of my data. I will paste what i started with on the Proxmox forum and will elaborate with the current situation.

after years of service, my proxmox host decided to give up on me, at the right moment when i was planning to replace with a new host (not brand new but still new storage) and while i was preparing it building the raid and so on on the new server.

The failing host is a DL380 G8 Dual Xeon E5-2430L 64GB of RAM with a P822 RAID card with 2 LUN configured :
20x 900GB SAS 10K rpm Seagate disks (with 2 hot spare configured) RAID 10 (root LUN, containing LVM local and local-thin where VMs, ISO images and backups are by default stored)
24x 2TB SAS 7.2K rpm Seagate disks (with 2 hot spare) RAID 6 for pure data storage

running on Proxmox 7.4, updated recently (one week ago or so).
I was making some benchmark on the new system to configure my RAID 10 of SSDs for best performance setting up the cache controller, the physical devices cache and so on, and comparing with only 4 benchmarks i run on my old host, just to see how the new system would perform.
I ran those 2 commands, one in read and one in write operation for 4K and 1M chunk size :

```
fio --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --sync=1 --rw=read --bs=4K --numjobs=1 --iodepth=1 --runtime=60 --time_based --name seq_read --filename=/dev/sda
fio --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --sync=1 --rw=write --bs=4K --numjobs=1 --iodepth=1 --runtime=60 --time_based --name seq_read --filename=/dev/sda
fio --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --sync=1 --rw=read --bs=1M --numjobs=1 --iodepth=1 --runtime=60 --time_based --name seq_read --filename=/dev/sda
fio --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --sync=1 --rw=write --bs=1M --numjobs=1 --iodepth=1 --runtime=60 --time_based --name seq_read --filename=/dev/sda
```

of course, like a bloody idiot, i did run the "write" benchmark on my old host without paying attention to the output filename ==> the disk itself and not a file :(
Of course, i didn't noticed that, and finally when i found the best settings for my new host, i wanted to restart it and do a clean install. I did reboot the old host instead and of course, as a result of the `fio` command run in write, i killed the beginning of the disk and therefore the boot partition (and probably some more).
My setup is the following :

```
Controller Status OK
Serial Number PDVTF0BRH8Y1RD
Model Smart Array P822 Controller
Firmware Version 8.32
Controller Type HPE Smart Array
Cache Module Status OK
Cache Module Serial Number PBKUD0BRH8V4FT
Cache Module Memory

Logical Drive 01

Status OK
Capacity 5029 GiB
Fault Tolerance RAID 1/RAID 1+0
Logical Drive Type Data LUN
Encryption Status Not Encrypted

Logical Drive 02

Status OK
Capacity 37259 GiB
Fault Tolerance RAID 6
Logical Drive Type Data LUN
Encryption Status Not Encrypted
```

If i start over the USB Proxmox installation, the boot LVM is missing, not detected at all :

the volume detected is the second one, the data storage.
As the volume is even not detected, i don't even know where to start.
I tried to run testdisk, but not sure how relevant this tool is in getting back the partition like that, what i can say is that he does see LVM2 volumes in my /dev/sda :

[image]

What i did so far (also explain on the Proxmox forum) after i figured out my mistake with `fio` is to make a clone of the disk on another host using `dd` command and i plan to only work on this copy, to not kill more the destination disk.
The luck i have is that i know how my partitions were structured, i kept a trace of that. So the question would be, how to recreate it without deleting more than i already did and try to recover as much as there is left on that host. The speed of the disks were at 1000MB/s writing overall, so as it ran for 60sec, let's assume i deleted from 60 to 70GB of data on that disk, and as the root partition was around 1.8TB, i hope that the "data" volume is intact within the LVM. What is your opinion on that ?

Thanks for the help folks and don't beat the bloody idiot, i wanted to recycle the old server as my backup server and not face the current situation, isn't that ridiculous ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit :
Testdisk seem to find some traces of the "data" partition, but he sees it as a linux filesystem, and not a LVM volume (don't pay attention to the different volume of the disk, i used a larger disk to `dd` the source one).

So it looks like there are traces of something left.
One (maybe) stupid idea, a friend proposed to use a `grep` function over the disk seeking for the metadata file, does it start always with the same text ? Could it be something doable ?
[image]

Comment: You can probably determine (roughly) how much it wiped with `hexdump -C -n 64 --skip=1G` repeat with 2G 4G 8G 16G ... until it starts looking different. Even if it wiped less data than expected, it all depends where those root, swap LVs were allocated within LVM. If those were ever grown, or if pve-data was created first... that changes where this thin volume metadata is located too. Then there might be multiple segments if it was ever resized. It's complicated... basically you have to recover tmeta to make any sense of tdata but you don't even know where those are located. It's a puzzle...

Comment: LVM keeps backups of its metadata in /etc/lvm/* you don't have backups of those files by any chance?

Comment: No metadata backup unfortunately.

Comment: About the hexdump, i tried using that command : hexdump -C -n 64 --skip=1G /dev/sda and then the same with --skip=2G, it was already looking different between 1G and 2G (not much, but not the same either).

Comment: fio keeps repeating the same pattern (with alterations but it looks similar enough), or at least that's what it looked like to me when testing superficially in a VM earlier. I rarely use fio so not very familiar with it.

Comment: You can try, 1) determine how much had been overwritten with hexdump (show results), 2) try to find LVM metadata `strings -t d /dev/sda | grep 'Generated by LVM2'`, 3) lacking metadata, assuming it was never resized (no fragmentation within LVM), try hexdump with the offsets and sizes from your photo. sda3 sector 2099200, +2048 lvm metadata, +1677216 swap, +2657615872 root (order of swap, root, data is unknown, depends on order of creation). Assuming your pics are accurate… lsblk and fdisk -l don't match for size of sda3… 4) you can run `photorec` to find some small file bits… it's a mess

Comment: Ok, i think i have to make my mind and move on with reconfiguring everything by hand and that's it. What would you suggest to move my data logical volume to the new server ? Should i use the proxmox function to move data by plugging the 2 drive bays with the hardware raid card. It is 2 external bays plugged with external SAS cable to a hardware raid card, so i could install that card in the new server and have the access to my data from there. Or is that a bad idea ?